# How much data can a socket store in its buffer before read?

Tags: sockets, networking, client-server

I have a client / server application where clients send messages to the server. Due to a legacy library that I use, my server cannot read immediately but must wait for a condition to come true until it reads the messages. How much data can a socket store? Is there a fixed buffer size/limit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the size of the socket receive buffer, whose default value varies among operating systems. You can control it from your application via `setsockopt()` and the SO_RCVBUFSIZE option.

Comment: This is pretty much what I already expected, but could not find the right bits of information for some reason :/. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on many factors of which many you can't control. This is not the correct approach.

You should read the data as soon as it is available, but only *process* it if the conditions are met.

Edit: I guess I misinterpreted the question, see @EJP's answer.

Comment: It depends on exactly one factor, which you can control. -1